# Dismissing the tabbar view controller in swift

Tags: swift, tabbar

I have `loginViewController` and I am pushing a `tabBarViewcontroller` which is has 3 tabs

Below's my code:

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
var profileStoryBoard: UIStoryboard!
profileStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Login", bundle: nil)
let viewcontroller: MainViewController = profileStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false)
```

I then dismiss the `loginViewController` and push the `tabBarViewController`.

Now I have a sign out button on all 3 tabBar items, but it is not working.

Here's my  code:

```
var profileStoryBoard: UIStoryboard!
profileStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)      
let viewcontroller : LoginViewController = profileStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false)
```

I am new to swift so I don't know what mistake I might be doing here.

Comment: Show the storyboard screenshot.

Comment: presenting a `viewController` modally is different from pushing to the navigation stack. Could you add more code for context?

Comment: Try this out for dismissing your tab bar controller:   `self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { _ in })`  Completion can be `nil`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is pushing another controller on top of the stack

```swift
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false)
```

You instead want to go back one label. You should use this:

```swift
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```